# fopen() returns NULL but open() syscall returns proper file descriptor?

Tags: c, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, fopen, lseek

I've been trying to run this very simple C code on Ubuntu 20.04LTS

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   
    FILE *f;
   
    f=fopen("tree.txt","r");
    if(f==NULL){
        perror("fopen");
        exit(1);
    }
    //readTree();
    return 0;
}
```

But no matter what I've tried so far fopen still returns this eror:

```
fopen: No such file or directory
[1] + Done
```

First thing I assumed was that the program didn't have permission to open the file, but the permissions are set correctly:

```
ls -la tree.txt
-rw-rw-rw- 1 mor mor 7 mar 26 20:43 tree.txt
```

Next I tried to change the location of the file to /home or to specify a full path instead of the file name; still the same result

Now comes the part I can't wrap my head around, *when running the script under Strace, it appears to work fine*, at least for now

```
execve("./B1", ["./B1"], 0x7ffe586e59b0 /* 26 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55cd150ea000
arch_prctl(0x3001 /* ARCH_??? */, 0x7fff084d4590) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=156877, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 156877, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fcadcd70000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\360q\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
pread64(3, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\5\0\0\0GNU\0\2\0\0\300\4\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 32, 848) = 32
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0\t\233\222%\274\260\320\31\331\326\10\204\276X>\263"..., 68, 880) = 68
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2029224, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fcadcd6e000
pread64(3, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\5\0\0\0GNU\0\2\0\0\300\4\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 32, 848) = 32
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0\t\233\222%\274\260\320\31\331\326\10\204\276X>\263"..., 68, 880) = 68
mmap(NULL, 2036952, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fcadcb7c000
mprotect(0x7fcadcba1000, 1847296, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fcadcba1000, 1540096, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x25000) = 0x7fcadcba1000
mmap(0x7fcadcd19000, 303104, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x19d000) = 0x7fcadcd19000
mmap(0x7fcadcd64000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1e7000) = 0x7fcadcd64000
mmap(0x7fcadcd6a000, 13528, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fcadcd6a000
close(3)                                = 0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fcadcd6f540) = 0
mprotect(0x7fcadcd64000, 12288, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x55cd14c84000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fcadcdc4000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7fcadcd70000, 156877)          = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55cd150ea000
brk(0x55cd1510b000)                     = 0x55cd1510b000
openat(AT_FDCWD, "tree.txt", O_RDONLY)  = 3
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

The openat() call returns a small positive integer, which is normal behavior from what I read so far

Lastly, what really grinds my gears is that the **output of Strace above differs from the output I received just a couple minutes before**. For some reason I can't seem to recreate that output but the gist of it is this:

-openat() returns 3

-**lseek(fd, -9, SEEK_CUR)** is called and returns **-1 ESPIPE Illegal seek** please excuse my syntax here, I'm writing it from memory.
Also why is the offset a negative integer? Is that normal?

And why was lseek() called the first couple of times, but not now?

Reading man on lseek [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html) it says that

> On Linux, using lseek() on a terminal device fails with the error
> ESPIPE.

also the error descriptor

> ESPIPE fd is associated with a pipe, socket, or FIFO.

I believe the first quote to be unrelated, plenty of threads online with people managing to use fopen() on linux. When it comes to the error descriptor, it is beyond my level of understanding.

[image: Screenshot of the error case]

renderer1.log :

```
[2021-03-27 23:08:46.895] [renderer1] [error] Unexpected: The specified task is missing an execution: Error: Unexpected: The specified task is missing an execution
    at S.getTaskExecution (/snap/code/59/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:90:48749)
    at S.$onDidStartTaskProcess (/snap/code/59/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:90:46905)
    at c._doInvokeHandler (/snap/code/59/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:90:10509)
    at c._invokeHandler (/snap/code/59/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:90:10201)
    at c._receiveRequest (/snap/code/59/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:90:8871)
    at c._receiveOneMessage (/snap/code/59/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:90:7673)
    at /snap/code/59/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:90:5782
    at g.fire (/snap/code/59/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:57:1836)
    at p.fire (/snap/code/59/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:65:15443)
    at /snap/code/59/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:106:29119
    at g.fire (/snap/code/59/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:57:1836)
    at p.fire (/snap/code/59/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:65:15443)
    at t._receiveMessage (/snap/code/59/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:65:20693)
    at /snap/code/59/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:65:17587
    at g.fire (/snap/code/59/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:57:1836)
    at l.acceptChunk (/snap/code/59/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:65:12808)
    at /snap/code/59/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:65:12156
    at Socket.E (/snap/code/59/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/services/extensions/node/extensionHostProcess.js:106:12375)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:295:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:271:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:212:10)
    at Pipe.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23)
```

This is all I could come up with, apparently it's not good enough.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Nothing in your post describes the actual error case - your code is fine, your directory listing looks fine, and you sent us a trace of a working condition. Can you provide any more details of the *failing* case to help us understand?

Comment: Are you running this through an IDE? A common problem in such cases is that the file is not placed in the IDE's working directory. Please be clearer in describing how you are running the code - show the exact log of building the code, running the program and listing the full contents of the directory.

Comment: @CarlNorum I updated the question with a screenshot of the failing case, also as specified the strace output I posted does come from the failng case as well

Comment: The file descriptor on the call of `lseek()` is 0, not 3 of your file. The call checks `stdin`.

Comment: Did you try to run the program from the command line, with the file in the current directory?

Comment: @kaylum running it through Visual Studio Code, file is placed in the same directory as the .c file (dir should be visible in the screenshot i upoaded). Also added the log file

Comment: Did you copy and paste the output or did you retype it? If you copied and pasted, then why `mar 26` in the `ls` output instead of `Mar 26`, and why `[1] + Done` instead of `[1]+ Done`?

Comment: I don't use VS Code so can't give you specific advice (someone else may). But this really looks like an IDE issue. When an IDE runs the program it typically does not do it from the source tree. So you need to place the input file into the location the IDE runs from.  Or as a quick test use an absolute path in the `fopen` call.

Comment: @thebusybee Yes, that seems to work fine. But then why does it not run in vsc?

Comment: @Mor010101, put something like `system("pwd")` in the code to see what directory it gets launched in. (That's the quick and dirty way, really you'd use `getcwd()` or `get_current_dir_name()` or such.)

Comment: @kaylum That solved it!! Using an absolute path. (I'm new to stackOverflow, is it common etiquette to answer my own question and mention the contributors? or should i wait for someone to post an answer so i can accept it)

Comment: Note: Using an absolute path is just a test. Would not do that in real code as such hard coding makes the code too rigid - it will break in other environments. Also, feel free to answer your own question.

Comment: @ilkkachu Yeah, that seems to have been the problem. 'system("pwd")' printed the path of the directory containing the directory in which B1.c is located. Moving the .txt file to that dir solves the issue. (also could change the program execution dir with 'chdir()' i think)

Comment: @Mor010101, yep. Try and see if the IDE has a setting somewhere, perhaps per-project,  for what directory it uses. In general, the most flexible way would be for the tool to take any filenames as command line arguments (or such): that would make it more flexible to use in a an environment different from yours. Not that it's probably the first thing in your mind right now, but, you know, in general. :)

Comment: If you are a computer app rather than an interactive meat-user, you should not be using CWD!  I don't understand why so many developers fall for that one:((

Comment: @MartinJames what alternative would there be to using cwd?

Comment: Use relative paths, use absolute paths, use paths retrieved by OS API calls....

Comment: @MartinJames oh yeah that is better. I just wanted a 'quick' solution, as I'm a first year uni student and most of the code we write is very very simlpe.

Answer (score 0):

To sum it up, my issue was that the working directory of the .c program and the directory in which i had saved the .txt file were different. There are many ways to get around this issue.

### Try using an absolute path in the fopen directory. For example:

```
    FILE*f; f=fopen("/home/user/Desktop/file.txt","r");
```

this only works as a test, as it makes the code too rigid(answer provided by @kaylum)

### Changing the working directory using [chdir()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/chdir-in-c-language-with-examples/)

simple code that changes directory to the one specified by the user, opens file with name and mode specified by user; printing cwd using [getcwd()](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.bpxbd00/rtgtc.htm)
(part of the answer provided by @ilkkachu)

```
//puts cwd in *str and prints cwd if successful, otherwise prints error 
void getdir(char *str, unsigned int str_size)
{
    
     if(getcwd(str,str_size)==NULL){
        perror("getcwd()");
        exit(1);
    }else
        printf("Current working dir: %s\n",str);
}

//reads directory path and sets it as new working dir
int changeDir()
{
    char cwd[256];
    printf("New woking dir path= ");
    scanf("%s",cwd);
    if(chdir(cwd)!=0){
        perror("chdir()");
        return -1;
        }
    getdir(cwd,sizeof(cwd));
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
   
    FILE *f;
    char cwd[256],fmod[5];
    
    getdir(cwd,sizeof(cwd));
    //reads new path until an existing one is inputted
    while(changeDir()!=0);

    printf("File name: ");
    scanf("%s",cwd);
    printf("File mode: ");
    scanf("%s",fmod);
    
    f=fopen(cwd,fmod);
    if(f==NULL){
        perror("fopen");
        exit(1);
    }


    //reads first line of file and prints it to console
    fscanf(f,"%[^\n]",cwd);
    printf("%s",cwd);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Code terminal output:

```
Current working dir: /home/moro/Documents/TP-Lab
New woking dir path= /home/moro/doesNotExist
chdir(): No such file or directory
New woking dir path= /home/moro/Desktop
Current working dir: /home/moro/Desktop
File name: input.txt
File mode: r
THIS IS A TEST FILE[1] + Done
```

### Changing the current working directory in Visual Studio Code settings

Go to

> Settings>Terminal>Integrated: Cwd

You can specify a start path there

> Terminal › Integrated: Cwd
> An explicit start path where the terminal will be launched, this is used as the current working directory (cwd) for the shell process. This may be particularly useful in workspace settings if the root directory is not a convenient cwd.

There probably are smoother ways to go about this, but for my use case these options are more than good enough. If i find the time i will add more solutions to this answer